# For any polynomial with integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials

If a polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients has three distinct integer zeros, then show that $P(n)\neq1$ for any integer $n$.

Comment: Hint:  first suppose that $P(x)$ has degree $3$.  Can you factor it?

Comment: $q(n)(n-a)(n-b)(n-c)=1$ with $n,a,b,c$ integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch:

1. Suppose that $P(a)=P(b)=P(c)=0$ where $a,b,c$ are integers.
2. Suppose that there exists a $d$ such that $P(d)=1$.
3. Prove that $(d-a)\mid P(d)-P(a)=1$.  Hint: Prove $(d-a)\mid (d^k-a^k)$ by factoring.
4. This gives three distinct divisors of $1$, do you detect a contradiction?

Comment: Got it...thank you...